# How to get hosts and associated roles from Cloudera API?

Tags: api, cloudera-cdh

I cannot find roles in the below rest api call:

/api/v15/cm/service/roles

Comment: Via get or post?

Comment: I want it via get

Answer (score 0):

I think.. you really need to do this by Cluster.  Like this....

```
/api/v15/clusters/<clustername>/hosts
```

That will give you a list of "hostIds" for the given cluster.  You can get a list of the details for each one by running:

```
/api/v15/hosts/<hostId>
```

The "real" server name is in there.. as well as the services for it.

Hope that helps.